# Showing `title` in html reverts the cursor back from `context-menu`

Tags: html, css

I have html element with `title` attribute and `cursor=context-menu`. When I mouse over it, it shows cursor with the context menu icon. When I wait a bit the title text appears and cursor changes back to default.
Now when I move the mouse it shows the title quite quickly in the other element and the cursor stays as the default, not `context-menu` as I've set it.
Ideally I would have to cursor always be `context-menu` even when showing title text.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and put enough code into your question so we can see the problem.